# Python - Extract multiple lists from a list of lists by index

Tags: python

Is there an efficient way to loop through a list of lists and extract the 1st element of each list into another list, 2nd elements into another one, etc. Such as:

```
x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6] , [7, 8, 9]]
y1 = [i[0] for i in x]
y2 = [i[1] for i in x]
```

Is there a way to extract y1 and y2 in a single list comprehension?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `zip`:

```
>>> x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6] , [7, 8, 9]]
>>> for l in zip(*x):
...     print l
... 
(1, 4, 7)
(2, 5, 8)
(3, 6, 9)
```

You can use [`itertools.izip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) in place of `zip()` to make an iterator instead of a list.